# Can't ssh in my AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

Below the is the error being spit back out.  I wish I could add more but I'm not sure what exactly the issue around the public key is.  I am adding more words because my edit can not be submitted without more non-code characters.

command ->

```
ssh -v -i ta-tester-8.pem ec2-18-191-187-131.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to ec2-18-191-187-131.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file ta-tester-8.pem type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file ta-tester-8.pem-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
    debug1: Authenticating to ec2-18-191-187-131.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'xxxx'
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:T5bQqn3DGc+IDbgF7/JUhkARudvw4Rc5Io/vMYm2JpU
    debug1: Host 'ec2-18-191-187-131.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /Users/xxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:37
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: ta-tester-8.pem
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    xxxx@ec2-18-191-187-131.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Rember yo need to access with hey file to login in your instance, using the -i parameter

Comment: Please edit your question to show the command that you are using to login to the instance.

Comment: I added everything from the command till the end

Comment: And from this question I learnt how handy -v flag can be while debugging SSH connection issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are not providing a **Username** to connect. If it is a standard Amazon Linux instance, then use `ec2-user` as the username:

```
ssh -v -i ta-tester-8.pem ec2-user@ec2-18-191-187-131.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Without that name, it has been trying to login with the same username as on your system (`xxxx`).